# Embedding React into HTML-Page - Image URL's not working

Tags: html, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, webflow

Created a react component, built the app and uploaded the built to a public AWS S3 bucket. From there, I included the script into a normal HTML page (on another domain). Everything works just fine, however, the react app can't find the images.

How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm guessing your images are in a local directory in the S3 bucket. When you include the React script file, React will look in the local directory of the **new HTML file** not the bucket where you uploaded the original app.

Comment: Yes excatly. How could one solve that?

Answer (score 1):

React scripts normally search for images in a local directory.
to load images in other domain you had to:

- add Static website hosting property to your s3 bucket.
- update your React script and load image with the s3 website url.

the public URL must be something like:

```
     import React from "react";
     import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

     function App() {
       return (
         <img 
          src="http://{s3BucketWebStaticHostingURL}/path/to/image.jpg"/>
       );
     }

     const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
     ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```